# "[Site]" in email subject line when django-allauth sends email

Tags: django, mailgun, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth for user authentication in my Django project. Right now account emails are being sent through MailGun.

When a `password reset` or `confirm account` email comes through, `[Site]` is printed in the subject line of the email as such:

```
[Site] Password Reset E-mail
```

How can I remove this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ''` in your settings. All-auth has a ton of custom settings... I have learned that anytime something is configured not to my liking, there's probably a setting available as opposed to having to override their code. https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html